# No such property: ToInputStream for class: Script4

Tags: docker, gremlin, janusgraph, kryo

I have a situation where I want to import my graph data to database.I am having janusgraph(latest version) running with cassandra(version 3) and elasticsearch(version 6.6.0) using Docker.I have been suggested to use gryo format.So I have tried this command

```
graph.io(IoCore.gryo()).reader().create().readGraph(ToInputStream.from("my_graph.kryo"), graph);
```

but ended up with an error

```
No such property: ToInputStream for class: Script4
```

The documentation I am following is [here](https://help.compose.com/docs/janusgraph-importing-graphs).Please take a look and put me in a right procedure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToInputStream` is not a function of Gremlin or JanusGraph. I believe that it is only a function of IBM Compose so unless you are running JanusGraph on that specific platform, this command will not work.

Versions of JanusGraph that utilize TinkerPop 3.4.x will support the [`io()` step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#io-step) and this is the preferred manner in which to load gryo (as well as graphson and graphml) files.

```
Graph graph = ... // setup JanusGraph instance
GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withGraph(graph); // might use withRemote() here instead depending on how you are connecting I suppose
g.io("graph.kryo").read().iterate()
```

Note that if you are connecting remotely - it seems you are sending scripts to the Docker instance given your error - then be sure that that "graph.kryo" file path is accessible to Docker. That's what's nice about `ToInputStream` from Compose as it allows you to access remote sources.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand what is meant by specific platform. As I am not having minimum knowledge in this field, any reference or documentation will be helpful.

Comment: IBM Compose (where the link in your question points to) is a hosting of JanusGraph on their cloud platform. You might also download JanusGraph yourself and run it locally on your computer and think of that as a different platform. On IBM Compose you will have a `ToInputStream` function but on your local system you will not. It is IBM's packaging on compose that provides that, not the open source JanusGraph project or Gremlin itself.

Comment: So is there any alternative solution for this scenario Or any idea on how to proceed with the gryo. If there are other alternatives, Please suggest me for importing graph data to database.

Comment: Just don't use the `ToInputStream` function and only use functions supported  by Gremlin and JanusGraph The Practical Gremlin book has lots of examples of using Gremlin's `io()` step for example - http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#graphmlandjsonintro Gryo specific usage with `io()` step can be found here:  https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gryo - I've updated my answer a little bit to include an example.